# Debug.Assert versus conditional compilation

Tags: c#, debugging, conditional-compilation

Consider the code below:

```
#if DEBUG
    if (Systems.Contains(system))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("System already registered");
#endif

    Debug.Assert(!Systems.Contains(system), "System already registered");
```

Previously I used to do the former, I've since discovered `Debug.Assert`.

Is there a reason why I should not always prefer `Debug.Assert`?

1. It only exists in debug code (it has the attribute `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`).
2. It seems to me to be more suited to my intention (code sanity checks, rather than raising exceptions to be handled later).
3. It's less code to write.

Comment: Debug.Assert wins every time for me

Comment: to be honest I'd rather throw in release mode as well 99% of the time, so rarely use either

Comment: @jk.: True. In this case it's for a game, so checks like these are best avoided if possible but are ok for getting an error sooner when debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use Debug.Assert(), because this class is complied with the DEBUG conditional as well:

```
[Conditional("Debug")]
```

> Indicates to compilers that a method call or attribute should be
> ignored unless a specified conditional compilation symbol is defined.
>
> ConditionalAttribute is applied to the methods that are defined in the
> Debug and Trace classes.
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info, although I was already aware of the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) (edited to make that clear).

Comment: Great, so then I would use your "3. It's less code to write." as the main reason for Debug.Assert() :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave this open for a while longer to see if there are any other responses (haven't forgotten to accept).